# Problem with a SWF running in a browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made an AS3 animation with Flash. The SWF work perfectly playing directly in the Flash Player.

If I read the SWF file in a browser, interactions like "onRollOver" or "onEnterFrame" doesn't work anymore.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly embed your .SWF?  Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your .SWF files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the browser debug player installed if testing, so you can see if there are any errors.

Comment: Ok i test it, no bug in my actionscript. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I find the bug ! The first line of my actionscript was : 
*stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;*
With this my swf file doesn't have any response when I roll over it. When I embed the SWF file I use a part of this : . May be such of a conflict...

In the HTML I properly embed my .SWF with SWFObject. Great, thanks for your help !